# How to organize pyramid of images using bootstrap grid system

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 9 images that i'm using to create a pyramid of images with:

```
    []  []
  []  []  []
[]  []  []  []
```

Each image has equal square dimensions of about 270px * 270px.

I have it setup so that the bottom row looks like:

```
<div class="col-xs-3 img-hover">
    <img>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3 img-hover">
    <img>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3 img-hover">
    <img>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3 img-hover">
    <img>
</div>
```

And the top row looks like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-3"></div>
<div class="col-xs-3 img-hover">
    <img>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3 img-hover">
    <img>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3"></div>
```

But the middle row i'm not sure how i can arrange the spacing and image column size to make it.

Right now i'm doing:

```
<div class="col-xs-1"></div>
<div class="col-xs-3 img-hover">
    <img>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 img-hover">
    <img>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3 img-hover">
    <img>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-1"></div>
```

But that causes the center image to have odd spacing and doesn't arrange the grid correctly.

Is there a better way of doing this to split a 12 column grid system for '5' sections?

Answer (score 0):

Don't quote me on this but maybe you shouldn't be using bootstrap's grid for this, really.

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/defaye/ao9mkvup/) is my quick mock-up if this helps, though.

```
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/135">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/135">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/135"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/135"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/135"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3"><img src="http://placehold.it/135"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"><img src="http://placehold.it/135"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"><img src="http://placehold.it/135"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"><img src="http://placehold.it/135"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have create it using `.offset` to remove extra div.

First row :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-4 img-hover">
        <img>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 img-hover">
        <img>
    </div>
</div>
```

Second Row :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-3 img-hover">
        <img>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 img-hover">
        <img>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 img-hover">
        <img>
    </div>
</div>
```

Third Row:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 img-hover">
        <img>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 img-hover">
        <img>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 img-hover">
        <img>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 img-hover">
        <img>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/Tokipudi/ybcd6aqg/1/) is the best I could do using Bootstrap only.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-push-2 text-center">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/270">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-push-2 text-center">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/270">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/270" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/270" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/270" alt="">
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-pull-1 text-center">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/270" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-pull-1 text-center">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/270" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-push-2 text-center">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/270" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-push-3 text-center">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/270" alt="">
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```